# Java - How could change a relative URL String to an absolute URL if I know the domain?

Tags: java, url, href, java-6

So I'm trying to make a very basic web browser that accomplishes very specific tasks. However, I need to get the URL from relative URLs (such as in  tags. I can get both URLs, but I'm not sure how to approach relative URLs.

I am using Java 6 for compatibility with older systems (a lot older)

Basically, I have the URL "http://example.com/directory/page.html", then I have an  tag with the href= "newpage.html". I want to be able to get the URL "http://example.com/directory/newpage.html".

Moreover, if its href= "../newpage.html", I want to get "http://example.com/newpage.html",

and if its href="http://example.org/dir/anotherpage.html", I want to get the URL "http://example.org/dir/anotherpage.html".

Is there any good, clean way of doing this?

Comment: Convert it to a `URI` and use its methods, then convert it back. You don't have to worry about the double dots. The Web server will understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`uri.resolve()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve(java.lang.String)) method.

First create a `URI` from the base URL you loaded in Browser:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://example.com/directory/page.html");
URI newpage = uri.resolve("newpage.html");
System.out.println(newpage);
```

This will print:

> http://example.com/directory/newpage.html

The result for `uri.resolve("../newpage.html")` is :

> http://example.com/newpage.html

The result for `uri.resolve("http://example.org/dir/anotherpage.html")` is:

> http://example.org/dir/anotherpage.html

Of course you could check for an `http` prefix before and return the absolute URL instead of using `uri.resolve()`.

Even the usage of anchors, like `#myanchor` is possible. The result of `uri.resolve("#myanchor")` is:

> http://example.com/directory/page.html#myanchor

Comment: Worked exactly how I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Norconex `commons-lang` and the [URLNormalizer](https://github.com/Norconex/commons-lang/blob/master/norconex-commons-lang/src/main/java/com/norconex/commons/lang/url/URLNormalizer.java). Examine how the method `removeDotSegments()` is implemented if you want to write the code yourself.